# Iterate a list and add values to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary where values are obtained from iterating a list. The keys are in the tuple format (i,j).

e.g. if i = 3, j = 3, the keys are

(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3).

If my list is as follows,

`lst = list(range(1, 10))`

How do I obtain a dictionary like this?

`{(0, 0): 1, (0, 1): 2, (0, 2): 3, (1, 0): 4, (1, 1): 5, (1, 2): 6, (2, 0): 7, (2, 1): 8, (2, 2): 9}`

I have tried:

`dict = {(i,j): d for d in lst for i in range(1, i+1) for j in range(1, j+1)}`

but the values of my dictionary are strictly the last value of `lst`. This is my output instead:

`>>> {(0, 0): 9, (0, 1): 9, (0, 2): 9, (1, 0): 9, (1, 1): 9, (1, 2): 9, (2, 0): 9, (2, 1): 9, (2, 2): 9}`

Comment: If the value of each dictionary entry is calculated from the key, could you clarify the relationship between the key and the value or how the value is calculated?

Comment: @Kelo The first value of the list corresponds to (0,0), the second value corresponds to (0,1), third to (0,2)..... 
Basically in this format (i,j). I'm sorry I have trouble explaining this theoretically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have your list of tuples, `list_of_tuples`, then this would work:

```
d = {L:i for i,L in enumerate(list_of_tuples)}
```

or if a separate list of length `len(list_of_tuples)` exists, called `lst`, then you could do

```
d = {L:lst[i] for i,L in enumerate(list_of_tuples)}
```

Comment: You can do this instead `dict(enumerate(list_of_tuples))`

Comment: Cool. Didn't know that.

Comment: What if I do not have my list of tuples?

Comment: It seems your question implied you do have a list of tuples. i.e. `list_of_tuples=[(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)]`.